# Need help designing an airplane legal battery pack

Tags: batteries

I know this is not really a technical question but it might also help other people like me who design products with batteries. If it doesn't fit here, then please tell me where I can ask to find a solution, but I think that people who are experienced in electronics are the best to find an answer for this.

I know about the limit of 100Wh per battery pack that you can take on plane without approval of airlines. Recently I have noticed this being written on a Dewalt FlexVolt battery pack. It is a battery pack of variable voltage because its circuitry connects the cells as needed for the application.

It says, that is has capacity of 120Wh and next to it is says shipping 3x40Wh.
So does it means that if you divide the batteries electrically and not mechanically then it is fine to take it on a plane?

[image: Dewalt Flex Battery]

Thank you very much for any help

Comment: I am not reading it that way. What I am seeing is that for shipping purposes it should be regarded as 3x 40Wh batteries. But for use, it should be regarded as a single 120Wh battery. It doesn't really say anything about taking it on a passenger airplane with your luggage, whether checked or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its similar with the DeWalt tool batteries, they are 54V which is higher than allowed for shipping. Their solution is to physically disconnect the cells with a "transport cap", so they are actually 3x18V. When the battery is attached to the tool, the cells are ganged up in series to produce 54V.

https://www.2helpu.com/uploads/2016%20-%20XR%20FLEXVOLT%20Battery%20Shipping%20Website%20Copy%20ANZ.pdf

Comment: The photo in the OP's question is a piece from a DeWalt battery pack. You can see the model number: DCB606.